# Format time from SMS timestamp?

Tags: android, cursor

I am querying the SMS database using the following cursor:

```
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations?simple=true"); 
    Cursor cursor = _context.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, "normalized_date desc");
```

I am getting the dates back, but they are returning in a numerical format. Now I know that I can use the following:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatted = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm")
```

and make all of the times return whatever format I choose, but I was wanting to know if there was an easier way for me to determine whether or not that the timestamp is from today, earlier in the week, or past a week ago? Or another method that would be easier for me to determine this?

Answer (score 0):

For relative time you can take a look at `DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString`
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html

It'll have the desired output you want with 2 hours ago, 3 days ago etc.

Answer (score 0):

Any issues using a format string for SimpleDateFormat such as

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatted = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM d, ''yy")
```

or of the other myriad of options offered in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)?

Answer (score 0):

You can get `Calendar` object for your date and evaluate the range obtained relative to the current date.

```
    Calendar smsCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    smsCalendar.setTimeInMillis( smsTime );  
    year1=c.get(c.YEAR);
    week1=c.get(c.WEEK_OF_YEAR);

    Calendar lastWeek=Calendar.getInstance();       
    year2=c.get(c.YEAR);
    week2=c.get(c.WEEK_OF_YEAR);

    if(year1 == year2){
           if(week1 == week2}{
             //Do what you want here

           }
        }
    }
```